# Open UIViewController from URL scheme after push notification

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, url-scheme

I would like to open a specific UIViewController depending on an id I get from a URL scheme.

For exemple myapp://news/285 would open the UIViewController "news" displaying this specific one.

I get notified here :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)source
         annotation:(id)annotation
{   
    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"myapp"]) {

        NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

...

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

But how am I supposed to push the UIViewController ? I can't access to the navigation controller from here.

(I was thinking about sending a notification with NSNotficationCenter to my home page with the id, and pushing the UIViewController from there. What do you think ?)

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you view setup. So when you rootViewController is a UINavigationController then you can just use:

```
UINavigationController *navCon = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
[navCon pushViewController:myPushedVC animated:NO];
```

If not then maybe it is easier to go with the Notification approach

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that sending a notification through `NSNotificationCenter`. Your view controller could catch that notification and push the other view controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Tab bar, then use following code.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *) tabBar_Controller.selectedViewController;
```

you can set the selected view controller as per your requirement.

> If you are not using a tabbar

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
```

Now you can push to any view.